# search form with html , laravel and mysql

Tags: laravel, database, forms, model-view-controller, eloquent

I am adding a search form to my laravel application and I have a problem. Please help me.

Here is the html form:

```
<form action="{{ route('Test.search')}}" method="GET" >
{{csrf_field()}}
<input type="text" name="name" >
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

this is the road:

```
Route::get('/search',[
'as' =>'Test.search',
'uses' =>'\App\Http\Controllers\bankencontroller@search']);
```

method search:

```
public function search()
    {
   
  $sea=$_GET['name'];

  $b2= Test::where('name', 'lIKE', '%'.$sea.'%')->first();
      $b3=$b2->inhalt;
  // dd($b3);
  
return view('seite.exemple')->with(compact('b3'));
```

I am looking for data in my database in the tests table (with model Test). When I do dd($b3); I get the result I want, but I don't understand why I don't get the same result when I do
return view('seite.exemple')->with(compact('b3'));

Indeed the view seite.exemple is displayed without my searched data. can you help me please?

Comment: En Anglais, s'il vous plait

Comment: Please can you show the code in your `seite.exemple` file.

Comment: This is the code : <form action="{{ route('Test.search')}}" method="GET" >
{{csrf_field()}}
<input type="text" name="name" >
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

 <h3> Mon tableau</h3>

Answer (score 0):

instead use this

```
return view('seite.exemple')->with(compact('b3'));
```

pass the property to view like this

```
return view('seite.exemple', compact('b3'));
```

then in view you can access b3 value like

```
<span>{{ $b3 }}</span>
```

In the other hand, if you handle the "with" method it should be

```
return view('seite.exemple')->with('b3', $b3);
```